# How do I get every record in a specific grouping in SQL (hopefully by index)?

Tags: sql, impala

I have an Impala query aggregating millions of records into groups using group by on many colums

```
select col1, col3, col5, col7, col23 col24, count(*) as count 
from my_table 
group by col1, col3, col5, col7, col23 col24
```

result:

```
col1, col3, col5, col7, col23 col24, count
John, Michaels, USD, ABC, 123, AA, 1243560969
Ryan, Jones, USD, FCC, 101, BB, 5043855
James, Gerrity, YEN, FCC, 102, BA, 37876899
```

How do I get every record in a specific grouping in SQL (hopefully by index)?

I'm looking for something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM GROUP 3 IN (
  select col1, col3, col5, col7, col23 col24, count(*) as count 
  from y_table 
  group by col1, col3, col5, col7, col23 col24, count
)
```

Do you think this is possible? Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Now put one of the tags back, the one for the dbms you're actually using.

Comment: Why are you grouping by the field that you are aggregationg (count)? Also, using keywords as column aliases is not a good idea.

Comment: how do you define a group? what is group 3 ?? also - drop the count in the group by clause

Comment: @JohnHC That was a typo - would be great if you had any ideas to the overall SQL strategy

Comment: @ZahiroMor Thanks for your input and understanding, 3 would be the index (or any other method?) for getting all the values in a specific group

Comment: an overall strategy like - `select col1, col3, col5, col7, col23, col24, count(*) as cnt, some_function_to_form_groups as grp from my_table 
  group by col1, col3, col5, col7, col23, col24 having grp = 3 `

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select col1, col3, col5, col7, col23, col24,
 count(*) as cnt, some_function_to_form_groups as grp 
from my_table 
group by col1, col3, col5, col7, col23, col24 
having grp = 3
```

`some_function_to_form_groups` could be `left(col1,1) {or equivalent}` to get initials etc.